# Custom enum type in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.6

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't track it down at the moment.

In this example, why is `self` not defined?

```
class State(Enum):
    MY_STATE = type(self)('foo', 'bar')

    def __init__(self, some, thing):
        self.some = some
        self.thing = thing
```

Replacing `type(self)` with `State` also returns a `NameError` but for `State`.

Comment: `self` refers to the instance. Why should it be defined in the _class body_? It's only available inside methods and only if you named the first argument `self`.

Comment: what actually do you want the code for?

Comment: @MenglongLi To add parameters to the `Enum`'s members

Comment: Why do you need to add parameters to enum members? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Voting to close, since the answers mean I can't delete.  I've sucked myself into an XY problem which just required a step back.  Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not defined, because you refer to it in a *class variable*, not an *instance variable*. It is similar to using `this` in a `static` method in another language. The same for `State`, at the point you refer to it, the class has not  been defined yet and the name doesn't exist.

Comment: what does "refer to it in a class variable" mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this make it impossible to have an instance variable of type `State`?

Comment: That would go into infinite recursion anyway because the instance variable would itself create an instance variable, which would create an instance variable ....

Comment: How would you go about achieving something like [Java's Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)?

Comment: You can create an instance variable inside your `__init__`.  `self` exists inside it (it is autotically passed as argument). but be careful of infinite recursion.

Comment: @MTCoster: See the first code example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html for java-like enumeration

Comment: @MTCoster That depends on what exact feature you want from the Java enum. The basic one doesn't need an `__init__` or some instance variables at all.

Comment: The difference I'm seeing is that in Java, the elements are effectively instances of the enum class whereas Python uses a separate type for the elements

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In both python and java, the fields of an enumeration are just names for integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Why not extract another class like this:

```
from enum import Enum


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, some, thing):
        self.some = some
        self.thing = thing


class State(Enum):
    MY_STATE = MyClass('foo', 'bar')


print(State.MY_STATE == State.MY_STATE)
```

Comment: Would this be considered more pythonic than attempting to pack it into a single class?